Do you need to always specify a measure when integrating?
I've seen people name the "Riemann measure". I did some research, and they were likely referring to the Peano-Jordan measure, but I'm not sure about that. So, in order to formally define the Riemann integral, do you need measure theory? In particular, it was said that "using an integral means giving a measure".

No, Riemann integral does not require measure theory, and I would argue that a good number of textbooks do it without defining the Peano-Jordan measure, before or afterwards (out of curiosity, what does yours do?). Peano-Jordan measure is a finitely additive measure, which means that it isn't a measure in the current mainstream sense of measure, which would require it to be $\sigma$-additive. It is somewhat true that whenever you have a notion of $\int_X f(t),dt$, you are enticed to consider the sets $A$ such that $g(A)=\int_X \chi_A(x),dx$ exists in $[0,\infty]$, and how $g$ behaves.

@SassatelliGiulio okay thanks. So, just to be sure: the Riemann integral can be formally defined and used without using measure theory at all, right?

@SassatelliGiulio and so the statement "using an integral means giving a measure" is false?

I do not know.${}{}{}{}$

The term Riemannian measure is a reference to a measure defined on a Riemannian manifold from the Riemannian metric.
On ${\bf R}^n$ endowed with its standard euclidean structure, the integral associated to the Riemannian measure is the standard Riemann integral.
It is possible to define the Riemann integral of continuous functions on ${\bf R}^n$ without using a measure. This is done, for example, by using Riemann sums. An integral can be defined without reference to measure theory, as a positive linear form on continuous functions with compact support. It is a theorem due to Riesz that states that any such integral is associated to a measure if the space is metric locally compact.

Thank you. One question: say I have a certain integral which, using the Riemannian measure, equals $\alpha\in\mathbb R$. Now, in general, is there a measure that, if adopted, would make such integral equal $1$? Or, even more generally, an arbitrary $\beta\in\mathbb R$?

If you divide a positive measure by a (strictly) positive real number, you still get a positive measure. So the answer is yes if $\alpha$ is positive.
